How do to continue support for the DeveloperForce .NET Toolkit?
The project Force.Com Toolkit for .NET was the de facto .NET library from 2014 and still very usable, but hasn't had any PR activity since 2019.  There are a bunch of open issues and it appears that the current git project owner Wade Wegner is no longer at Salesforce, but Salesforce hasn't reassigned anyone to own the project.  The license still has a Salesforce copywrite on it.
https://github.com/wadewegner/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET
I'd like to continue using this library, as it is pretty robust, but it's getting to a maintenance point that could make it dead soon if not updated to reflect Salesforce API updates.
Is there another maintained fork of this library?  Has the .NET crowd moved on to something else?

Fork the project, the license allows it with a proper attribution.

@identigral, I thought of doing that, but then I'm more than likely going to be alone maintaining a fork that nobody else knows nor cares about.  I'd rather keep it within the current project.

To answer your question - there's no current. SF abandoned it because they believe .NET and other major stacks out of the box provide adequate support for calling REST/SOAP APIs. Most of the interfaces offered by SF to 3rd party apps are REST/SOAP.
